# How to solve an issue with pre selected layered navigation?

Tags: magento-1, magento-enterprise, layered-navigation

I'm using Magento 1.14.3.8, when I navigate through the categories sometimes some layered navigation items shows up selected.

[image: Magento 1 issue layered navigation pre selected]

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your layered navigation is having a cache issue, try to remove the cache on layered navigation.

```
<action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>null</s></action>
```